# Dynamic Highcharts with maximum xaxis points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I try to create dynamic highcharts. I use `series.addPoint`. It works fine but my chart adds points and doesn't move like here - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/). It can be with 100 points on the screen.
How can I make only 10 points on the screen and hide old points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series
Series.addPoint()'s third argument is a boolean that enables shifting. If your series is not shifting, try setting the third parameter to true.

As for the second part, are you sure you want to "hide" old data? Generally old data should be shifted off the end in a real time graph (which I assume is what you're going for). If you have too many points, you can make your x-axis smaller via Axis.setExtremes(). http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis

Comment: I want to show last 10 point, not all points. I update the chart every 10 minutes. And I can have 1000 points.

Comment: Can you post some code? As stated above, you can show less points by bringing your x-axis extremes closer together. You can grab data[0] and data[9], take their x values, and set them to the x-axis extremes. Then, technically all 1000 points will be part of the series, but the chart will only show 0-9.

Comment: Alright, well I can see that you haven't set shift to true in series.addPoint(). You haven't used setExtremes() either. Try adding it to your success callback in the ajax /get call.

Also, there's no html, so I can't run your chart and help you solve a problem.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I can't use AJAX from Jsfiddle.

Comment: I can't use setExtremes because I can have 40 last points with one value.

Comment: What do you mean 40 last points with one value? The same y-value? Then it's not a problem. Here is example with setting new extremes: http://jsfiddle.net/xpXLb/

Comment: `series.xAxis.setExtremes(x - 3600 * 24 * 1000,x);` solved my problem